# `String.methods - Object.methods` does not show all String class methods

Tags: ruby

I have run the following command in `irb` from Window's command console

```
String.methods - Object.methods
```

But I only get the following output

```
=> [:try_convert]
```

How can I show all methods of [String Class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have somewhat misleading title, because if you want to get a list of

> String class methods

then you are actually on the right track, because [Object#`methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-methods) returns a list of singleton methods.

But the documentation you have linked contains a list of instance methods, defined in `String` class.

To get this list, you want to use [Module#`instance_methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods):

```
String.instance_methods(false)
```

Comment: How do I return the methods list alphabetically?

Comment: @the_prole just use `sort` on the resulting collection) :)

Comment: @the_prole `String.instance_methods(false).sort`

Answer (score 1):

```
p String.instance_methods(false)
```